# On determinants and common divisors

Tags: matrices, divisibility, determinant, puzzle, decimal-expansion

> Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be natural numbers smaller than $10^n$. Write each $a_k$ in base $10$ and add $0$'s to the left of each decimal expansion, if needed, so that each $a_k$ is written with $n$ digits. Consider the matrix such that the entries of the $k$<sup>th</sup> row are the digits of $a_k$ (written in the same order). Let $d\in\mathbb N$ be such that $d$ divides each $a_k$. Prove that $d\mid\det A$.

For instance, suppose that $n=4$ and that your numbers are $3876$, $2784$, $684$, and $8388$, each of which is a multiple of $12$. Then$$A=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 8 & 7 & 6 \\  2 & 7 & 8 & 4 \\ 0 & 6 & 8 & 4 \\
 8 & 3 & 8 & 8\end{bmatrix}$$and $\det A=-360$, which is, in fact, a multiple of $12$.

I learned about this problem yesterday. I found it quite cute and I decided to share it with all of you.

**Note:** I know how to prove it.

Comment: Why then not answer your own question? Or why the asking?

Comment: @HandeBruijn But I *did* answer my own question. And I asked it here because, as I wrote, “I found it quite cute and I decided to share it with you all.”

Comment: OK, I see. Confused by info supplied by Close Votes interface .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t$ be the column vector with entries $1,10,10^2,\dots,10^{n-1}$.

Let $b$ be the column vector with entries $a_1,\ldots,a_n$.

Then $At = b$ and so $(\det A) t = \operatorname{adj}(A) A t = \operatorname{adj}(A) b$.

The first entry in both vectors says that $\det A$ is an integer linear combination of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. Therefore, every common divisor of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ also divides $\det A$.

This proof works unchanged for any base, not just $10$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my answer to my problem. Take the matrix $A$ and add the following columns to the last one:

- the first column times $10^{n-1}$;
- the second column times $10^{n-2}$;
- …
- the next to last column times $10$.

The new matrix $A^\star$ will have the same determinant  as $A$, but $A^\star$  is a matrix with integer entries such that the entries of its last column are the original numbers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. Since they are all multiples of $d$, $d\mid\det A^\star=\det A$.

Comment: My solution was the same as yours - I also noticed you could do the same thing with the transpose, which is kinda whacky. Do you have any interpretation of the value of this determinant, or is it just a cute problem?

Comment: @Joppy For me, it's just a cute problem.